# Will 500 THz frequency glow antenna while radiating?

Tags: antenna, frequency, light, radiation

I read 700 nm wavelength is visible light, for which frequency is 429 THz. If we produce that frequency, whether antenna will be radiating visible light?

Correct me if wrong.

Comment: Yes it would. Optical antennas are an area of active research.

Comment: If it didn’t glow, then its not radiating.

Comment: The best way to produce that frequency is with ... a LED or laser

Comment: The antenna would be shooting off photons. So yeah, I guess you could say it would be glowing. However, if the antenna is on the scale of a 700nm wavelength, it would be so small that it would look like a point source of light. Kind of like an LED junction, I guess.

Comment: It's not easy to produce a frequency that high with conventional electronics,  however the principle in reverse (receiving as opposed to transmitting) is currently being investigated as an alternative to solar cells (optical rectennas).

Comment: What about *amplitude* of 429 THz? Below a threshold, you get no light out. It is a tiny threshold. Also be aware that a warm antenna radiates at that frequency.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments.